# почему вкладки принимают такую форму при GridBagLayout?

Tags: java

[image: итог выглядит вот таким образом]

```
вот код:
    import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Tabbet extends JFrame 
{ 
JPanel panel1,panel2,panel3,panel4,panel5,panel6,panel7,panel8,panel9,panel10;//создание панелей 
JLabel label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8,label9,label10;//создание иконки 
JTabbedPane tabbed;//панель вкладок 
JTextField text1, text2,text3,text4,text5,text6, text7; 
//GridBagConstraints gbc =new GridBagConstraints (); 
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout(); 
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(); 


public Tabbet () 
{ 
super ("Health Certificate");//название окна 
//размещение 
setLayout(gbl); 





/*цвета*/ 


/*вкладки*/ 
panel1= new JPanel(); 
panel2= new JPanel(); 
panel3= new JPanel(); 
panel4= new JPanel(); 
panel5= new JPanel(); 
panel6= new JPanel(); 
panel7= new JPanel(); 
panel8= new JPanel(); 
panel9= new JPanel(); 
panel10=new JPanel(); 
/*поле для ввода текста*/ 
text1= new JTextField("id",20); 
gbc.gridwidth = 1; 
gbc.gridy = 0; 
add(text1, gbc); 

text2= new JTextField("birthday", 20); 
gbc.gridx = 1; 
gbc.gridy = 1; 
panel1.add(text2, gbc); 

text3= new JTextField("sex", 20); 
gbc.gridx = 2; 
gbc.gridy = 2; 
panel1.add(text3, gbc); 

text4= new JTextField("race", 20); 
gbc.gridx = 3; 
gbc.gridy = 3; 
panel1.add(text4, gbc); 

text5= new JTextField("blood type",20); 
gbc.gridx = 4; 
gbc.gridy = 4; 
panel1.add(text5, gbc); 

text6= new JTextField("heigh",20); 
gbc.gridx = 5; 
gbc.gridy = 5; 
/*gbc.gridwidth= 2; 
gbc.gridheight= 1;*/ 
panel1.add(text6,gbc); 

text7= new JTextField("weight",20); 
gbc.gridx = 6; 
gbc.gridy = 6; 
panel1.add(text7,gbc); 

/*вкладки*/ 
label1= new JLabel("Tabbet1"); 
label2= new JLabel("Tabbet2"); 
label3= new JLabel("Tabbet3"); 
label4= new JLabel("Tabbet4"); 
label5= new JLabel("Tabbet5"); 
label6= new JLabel("Tabbet6"); 
label7= new JLabel("Tabbet7"); 
label8= new JLabel("Tabbet8"); 
label9= new JLabel("Tabbet9"); 
label10=new JLabel("Tabbet10"); 

/*текст на вкладках*/ 
panel1.add(label1); 
panel2.add(label2); 
panel3.add(label3); 
panel4.add(label4); 
panel5.add(label5); 
panel6.add(label6); 
panel7.add(label7); 
panel8.add(label8); 
panel9.add(label9); 
panel10.add(label10); 

/*поле для ввода вкладка 1*/ 
panel1.add(text1,gbc); 








tabbed= new JTabbedPane(); 
tabbed.add ("1", panel1); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet2", panel2); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet3", panel3); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet4", panel4); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet5", panel5); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet6", panel6); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet7", panel7); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet8", panel8); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet9", panel9); 
tabbed.add ("Tabbet10", panel10); 
this.add(tabbed); 



this.setSize(700, 400); 
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
this.setVisible(true); 
setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

} 
public static void main (String args \[\]) 
{ 

new Tabbet(); 
} 
}


  \[1\]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD7nE.jpg][1]][1]
```

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0):

Надо задать размер для JTabbedPane, иначе контейнер создается дефолтного размера.

Comment: Спасибо, а Вы бы могли сказать как это сделать?

Comment: tabbed.setSize(400, 200);

Comment: к сожалению ничего не изменилось(